# AutoCompleteTextView : Drop down ListView background is black

Tags: android

In my application drop down listview of AutoCompleteTextView background turn black. How to change the drop down listview background color is white.

Here is my code

```
 <application
       android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
```

style.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    </style>
    <style name="Theme.MyCompatTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    </style>

</resources>
```

When i some changes in style.xml my Custom Action Bar is not working  and getting exception of this    **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:122)**

Comment: Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity

Comment: Thanks for the reply , I used custom listview with  AutoCompletetextView and set the background color is white.